# Integration by parts for definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x^2}{(x\sin\ x+\cos\ x)^2}=\left[\frac{-x\sec\ x}{(x\sin\ x+\cos x)^2}\right]_0^\frac{\pi}{2}+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sec^2 x dx$$

Is this a correct application of integration by parts for definite integral?

Clearly, $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sec^2 x\ dx$ does not exist.

The right hand side is in the form $\infty -\infty$.

If this is incorrect, how should integration by parts be applied here?

The indefinite integral is shown as below. By substituting the upper and lower limits, the answer of the definite integral should be $\frac{2}{\pi}$.

[image]

Comment: In general, it is possible to pick such an unfortunate combination of functions $u, ~dv$ for integration by parts, that $uv |_a^b$ doesn't exist. You have to be careful in what you pick

Comment: @YuriyS Then, what is the correct way to apply integration by parts here?

Comment: @YuriyS The expression on top is just the 5th line of the indefinite integral with upper and lower limits.

Comment: @YuriyS Sorry for a typo previously, it was supposed to be "u=x sec x, v=-1/(x sin x+cos x), u is undefined when x=pi/2". This is the same choice of u and v as the indefinite integral.

Comment: I see. Clearly, as you notice, for these particular limits this choice does lead to the undetermined expression $\infty-\infty$, which, however can be solved by taking indefinite integral in the second term first, and only applying limits to the final expression. It is allowed. Otherwise, you'd have to pick different $u,dv$

Comment: Formally, you can take the upper limit to be "$\pi/2-\epsilon$" in both terms, write them down explicitly, simplify, and then take the limit for $\epsilon \to 0$. It is also a widely used method, not only when it comes to integration by parts, but just various improper integrals

Comment: This method sounds reasonable but seems to be never taught in most Calculus courses. By the way, are there other appropriate choices for u and v?

Comment: It's possible there's no other choice which would simplify the problem as well as this one. As for the $\epsilon$ method, it's usually taught in theory as a part of the definition for the improper integrals. Sometimes it's not made clear that the method is useful in practice too